# local state not changing since props changes in getDerivedStateFromProps

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In my profile update screen i want to show error message

```
constructor(props){
   super(props)
   this.state={isError:false,
               message:''} 
 }

 static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
       if(nextProps.common.isFetching === false && nextProps.common.error === false) {
           return {isError:false, message:nextProps.common.message};
      } else if(nextProps.common.error === true){
           return {isError:true, message:nextProps.common.message};
        }
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
      if(this.props.common.isFetching === false) {
        if(!_.isEqual(this.props.common, prevProps.common) && this.props.common.error === false ) {
          ToastAndroid.show(this.props.common.message, ToastAndroid.SHORT);
          this.props.navigation.goBack()
        }
      }
    } 

 handleCloseNotification=()=>{
        this.setState({ isError: false});
  }  

render() {

  const showNotification = this.state.isError;
return (..............
        ...............
  <Notification
   showNotification={showNotification}
    handleCloseNotification= 
   {this.handleCloseNotification}
   type="Error"
   firstLine={this.state.message} />)}
```

Here if if  `prop` is true then local state `isError` will be true and error message will be show.And when i trigger `handleCloseNotification` local state `isError` should be false but its still true, error message is not gone,How to handle this situation?

Comment: Does the parent component ever set `nextProps.common.error` back to false, clear out the error data?

Comment: @DrewReese . if  `nextProps.common.error` is false then `isError` will be false.But if i try to change the value of `isError` via local function it will be reset to the value of `nextProps.common.error`

Answer (score 0):

> local state `isError` should be false but its still true,

Are you sure? Check this with `console.log(showNotification)` in `render`

Probably this flag/value is changed (to false) but `<Notification />` doesn't react to `showNotification` prop change - it can be used on mount only.

FIX:

`<Notification />` conditional rendering (entire):

```
{showNotification && <Notification 
  // component props
/>}
```

Comment: When i trigger function `handleCloseNotification `  in render value of `isError` is `true`

Comment: in this case `getDerivedStateFromProps` overrides `setState` change - use another variable for close, f.e. `errorRead`

Comment: I can't use separate variable to open and close?can we do any modification on  `getDerivedStateFromProps `?

Comment: Why not? Error still exists (from props, as fetching result) but can be unread/read (local state) - two different things.